# Understanding less trivial integration by trig substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

In less trivial integration problems, using trig substitution **(1.1)**, I keep fumbling over when and what trig identities to use.

- One trig identity I need help proving/understanding is how/why $\left[9-9sin^2\theta\right]=\left[9cos^2\theta\right]$ (?)

Once I've establish the original variables in terms of $\theta$, was is the best way, or maybe a general way if there is one, for dealing with the numerator equation? 
*For example, after the trig substitution, is the common next step another form of integration or is it merely simplification using identities. (etc.)*

In general it seems I keep drifting into harder, longer integration, so I'd like help getting a better understanding of 'the next step' following the substitution.

---

**(1.1) Example problems for reference:**
$$\int\frac{8u+4}{(u^2-u)-2}du \qquad \int\frac{6z-3}{(z^2+2z)+2}dz \qquad \int\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x^2}dx$$

Comment: Those parentheses in the first two integral's denominators are completely useless. Did you mean otherwise?

Comment: For the trig identity, $sin^2(\theta)+cos^2(\theta)=1$. Therefore multiply by $9$ and move the $sin^2(\theta)$ to the other side. Or are you asking for a proof of $sin^2(\theta)+cos^2(\theta)=1$?

Comment: @DonAntonio The reason the given problems are in this form is to emphasize the need to complete the square. It's trivial and could as easily be omitted, it's just a form of habit and convention I use.

Comment: @George1811 I didn't realize how obvious that was haha. That's exactly what I was asking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One example quick, without substitution or stuff:

$$\int\frac{8u+4}{u^2-u-2}du=4\int\frac{2u-1}{u^2-u-2}du+\frac83\int\left(\frac1{u-2}-\frac1{u+1}\right)du=$$

$$=4\log(u^2-u-2)+\frac83\left(\log\frac{u-2}{u+1}\right)+C=\ldots\text{(continue simplifying if you will)}$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got the "$+ 8/3\int\dots du$" part. Could you explain where this came from?

Comment: @ChongWaldo, you should try to do the algebra: $$\frac1{u-2}-\frac1{u+1}=\frac3{(u-2)(u+1)}$$ The $\;8\;$ comes from $$8u+4=4(2u-1)+8$$

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the only example out of the 3 for which the use of trig substitution is highly recommended is the integral $\int\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x^2}dx$.

$\int\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x^2}dx$

$\sin\theta=\frac{x}{3}$

$x=3\sin\theta$

$dx=3\cos\theta\ d\theta$

$\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)$

$\cos\theta=\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{3}$

$\sqrt{9-x^2}=3\cos\theta$

$=\int\frac{3\cos\theta}{9\sin^2\theta}\times3\cos\theta\ d\theta$

$=\int\cot^2\theta\ d\theta$

$=\int\left(\csc^2\theta-1\right)d\theta$

$=-\cot\theta-\theta+c$

$\cot\theta=\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x}$

$=-\frac{\sqrt{9-x^2}}{x}-\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)+c$